# Big query: Find all column name containing "surname" across all tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Newbie here. Is it possible to look for all tables that contain a certain column name such as "surname". Right now I have to click into the preview of each table to find this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Big Query the syntax for a query is

```
select * projectid.dataset.table
```

All information about a dataset can be queried by the following,
[more details here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name LIKE "surname%"
```

Or use the Data Catalog API to search and document Big Query.

Comment: Can you go into more detail please? Whats yourdataset, i mean which parts do I need to replace with what exactly? I see the little bee hive icon which when I click on it opens up nodes which then have individual tables nested under them.

Comment: Adding the following link into the mix, its the specific view for columns:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view

just replace the work `dataset` with what ever dataset in BQ you are looking for.  The information schemas are dataset specific though, so like Samuel said you may need to alternatively use the Data Catalog API if you want a larger scope in your search.